# !important doesn't work, doesn't extend 100%

Tags: css, width

Why doesn't my "!important work"?

```
<img src="images/logo.png" id="logo">
```

CSS:

```
html {
background-color: #ffffff;
}

body {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1080px;
}

#logo {
width: 100% !important;
}
```

But still the #logo doesn't extend 100%, only 1080px.

Comment: the 1080px _is_ the max width for the image because it's a parent container. All child containers cannot 'break' through it ...

Answer (score 2):

Your body is of `width: 1080px`, nothing that is of `width: 100%` can go beyond this.

Answer (score 0):

**now define your**

```
body{
min-width:1080px;
}
#logo {
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you parent element (in your case the body) has a fixed width (1080px) You can't extend your child element (in your case the #logo div) too 100% width of the window.

Now it will fill up 100% op the parent part, so 100% of 1080px.

Make your body 100% width and use a #wrapper or #container with a width of 1080px for the rest of the content. In that case you can exclude the #logo from your #container/#wrapper div and make it 100% of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Removed body width or set as 100%

Comment: but it's just the logo that i want to extend 100%. everything else I want 1080px